# Iterate through rows and identify which columns is true, assign new column the name of the column.header

Tags: python, dataframe, loops

I have the following DataFrame:

| Index | Time Lost | Cause 1 | Cause 2 | Cause 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 40 | x | Nan | Nan |
| 1 | 15 | Nan | x | Nan |
| 2 | 65 | x | Nan | Nan |
| 3 | 10 | Nan | Nan | x |

There is only one "X" per row which identifies the cause of the time lost column. I am trying to iterate through each row (and column) to determine which column holds the "X". I would then like to add a "Type" column with the name of the column header that was True for each row. This is what I  would like as a result:

| Index | Time Lost | Cause 1 | Cause 2 | Cause 3 | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 40 | x | Nan | Nan | Cause 1 |
| 1 | 15 | Nan | x | Nan | Cause 2 |
| 2 | 65 | x | Nan | Nan | Cause 1 |
| 3 | 10 | Nan | Nan | x | Cause 3 |

Currently my code looks like this, I am trying to iterate through the DataFrame. However, I'm not sure if there is a function or non-iterative approach to assign the proper value to the "Type" column:

```
cols = ['Cause1', 'Cause 2', 'Cause 3']

for index, row in df.iterrows():
            for col in cols:
                if df.loc[index,col] =='X':
                    df.loc[index,'Type'] = col
                    continue
                else:
                    df.loc[index,'Type'] = 'Other'

                continue
```

The issue I get with this code is that it iterates but only identifies rows with the last item in the cols list and the remainder go to "Other".

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: please provide your data as text in the question (use `df.to_dict('list')`)

Comment: I have added additional info and tables into post. Is this the information you are asking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `idxmax` on the boolean array of your data:

```
df['Type'] = df.drop('Time Lost', axis=1).eq('x').idxmax(axis=1)
```

*Note that this only report the **first** cause if several*

output:

```
   Time Lost Cause 1 Cause 2 Cause 3     Type
0         40       x     Nan     Nan  Cause 1
1         15     Nan       x     Nan  Cause 2
2         65       x     Nan     Nan  Cause 1
3         10     Nan     Nan       x  Cause 3
```